# How to use connection pooling for redis.StrictRedis?

Tags: python, django, redis

In order to be able to use redis lists in my django app, I have apealed to `redis.StrictRedis` connections instead of stardard django `cache.get` and `cache.set`. And I use this a lot in different functions.

My example codes are like:

```
 import redis
 r = redis.StrictRedis(unix_socket_path='/var/run/redis/redis.sock', db=3)
posts = r.lrange('posts', 0 , -1)
```

However I have encountered some performance issues (gunicorn threads being stalled at high load and I get frequent 502)

I suppose these are due to excessive `redis.StrictRedis` connections without using a pooling. If it's so, I'm wondering how can I use a connection pool instead of making a connection to redis for each data fetch?

Answer (score 4):

Each Redis instance that you create in turn all instances will create their own connection pool.You can overwrite this behaviour by using the singleton design in Python as below:

```
import redis

class RedisOperation(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
            cls.instance=redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=pool)
        return cls.instance

obj1=RedisOperation()
print(id(obj1))

obj2 = RedisOperation()
print(id(obj2))
```

Both above objects are referring to same redis connection pool.

For More details, please refer to [redis docs](https://pypi.org/project/redis/#connection-pools)